# How To make dropdown and textbox into single row

Tags: html, textbox

I want to make phone no. field into the form. The user should select the area code from dropdown box and just right to the drop down box their should be text box to enter the phone no. I want to use dropdown box and textbox into single  tag. When I try this it send automatically the second field ie textbox into second line by putting

tag automatically. When I use two textbox or two dropdown box then it works fine into single  tag.

I want to use one dropdown box and one textbox into single  tag.

Or are there any other method we can do this.

Please find the code I am using.

```
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td><label>Name:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="bftpro_name"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><label>Email:</label></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email"/></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>         
   <td><label>Phone No:</label></td>
    <td><select id="countries" style="width: 50%; name="countries">
    <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" style="width: 50%; name="field_2" value=""/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Download"/></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="bftpro_subscribe" value="1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="list_id" value="2"/>     
    </form>
```

Comment: Please reformat your code.

Comment: you can use `tabindex`? or can you create a fiddle

Answer (score 0):

You should put them into separate `<td>`

```
   <td><label>Phone No:</label></td>
        <td><select id="countries" style="width: 50%; name="countries">
        <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
        <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
        <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
        <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" style="width: 50%; name="field_2" value=""/></td>
```